# how to combine or join 2 MySQL queries together

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 following queries return the same columns:

first query is slightly modified one I found here in different post returning all day of the current month:

```
select null as id, 
       a.day, 0 as was_present, 
       0 as was_late, 
       0 as left_earlier, 
       null as student_id 
from (
        select 
           last_day(NOW()) 
          - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY as day
        from (
                select 0 as a 
                union all select 1 
                union all select 2 
                union all select 3 
                union all select 4 
                union all select 5 
                union all select 6 
                union all select 7 
                union all select 8 
                union all select 9
              ) as a
        cross join 
            (
                select 0 as a 
                union all select 1
                union all select 2 
                union all select 3 
                union all select 4 
                union all select 5 
                union all select 6 
                union all select 7 
                union all select 8 
                union all select 9
            ) as b
       cross join 
            (
                select 0 as a
                union all select 1 
                union all select 2 
                union all select 3 
                union all select 4 
                union all select 5
                union all select 6 
                union all select 7 
                union all select 8 
                union all select 9
            ) as c
    ) as a 
where a.day between DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') AND NOW() 
order by a.day
```

while the second is returning attendance data from the real table like this:

```
select * 
from student_attendance 
where student_id = ?1 
and (date between DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') AND NOW())
```

Sample data from second query look like this:

```
2   2019-10-01  1   0   0   5 
3   2019-10-02  1   0   0   5 
4   2019-10-03  1   0   0   5
5   2019-10-04  1   0   0   5
```

Now my question is how to combine them together to return only unique days of the month (1 record per day) where the real record from second query replaces fake record in first query when it exist. I tried to use union but it return duplicates.

Again, using union doesn't work, here is what it returns:

```
    2019-10-01  0   0   0   
2   2019-10-01  1   0   0   5
    2019-10-02  0   0   0   
3   2019-10-02  1   0   0   5
4   2019-10-03  1   0   0   5
    2019-10-03  0   0   0   
    2019-10-04  0   0   0   
5   2019-10-04  1   0   0   5
    2019-10-05  0   0   0
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what *you* want to do would all be very helpful.

Comment: I added sample of second query, first query return all data straight away (it doesn't use any tables). Please read my post to the end to find out the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with the UNION between the second query and the rows of the first query with date not present in the second query, something like this:

```
select * 
from student_attendance 
where student_id = ?1 and (date between DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') AND NOW())

UNION

select null as id, 
       a.day, 0 as was_present, 
       0 as was_late, 
       0 as left_earlier, 
       null as student_id 
from (
        select last_day(NOW()) - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY as day
        from (
                select 0 as a 
                union all select 1 
                union all select 2 
                union all select 3 
                union all select 4 
                union all select 5 
                union all select 6 
                union all select 7 
                union all select 8 
                union all select 9
              ) as a
        cross join 
            (
                select 0 as a 
                union all select 1
                union all select 2 
                union all select 3 
                union all select 4 
                union all select 5 
                union all select 6 
                union all select 7 
                union all select 8 
                union all select 9
            ) as b
       cross join 
            (
                select 0 as a
                union all select 1 
                union all select 2 
                union all select 3 
                union all select 4 
                union all select 5
                union all select 6 
                union all select 7 
                union all select 8 
                union all select 9
            ) as c
    ) as a 
where a.day between DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') AND NOW() 
    and a.day NOT IN (
                        select date 
                        from student_attendance
                         where student_id = ?1 and (date between DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') AND NOW())
                     )
order by a.day
```

Comment: Your way works for me best gents :). I need to use the query in java repository so it's better for me than another solution below.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a temporary table then do a LEFT JOIN to it:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE days
select a.day
 from (
 select last_day(NOW()) - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY as 
day
 from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 
union 
all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union         
all 
select 8 union all select 9) as a
 cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all     
select 3 
union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 
union all 
select 8 union all select 9) as b
 cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all 
select 3 
union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 
union all 
select 8 union all select 9) as c
  ) a where a.day between DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') AND NOW() order by 
a.day;

SELECT 
  id, days.`day`, was_present, was_late, left_earlier, student_id
FROM days
LEFT JOIN student_attendance sa ON days.`day` = sa.`day`;
```

Comment: Union returns duplicates so I have 2 records for 2019-10-01, one from dummy query and second from the real table and so on. I want just 1 record per day

Comment: @smoczyna - I modified the code after I saw the edits.  Could you do a temporary table then a LEFT JOIN?

Comment: Well I could but I also need to use the query in java repository so the standalone query without temp tables is better for me. Thanks anyway